# Quelle est la signification de l'expression « aussi bien pour » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, comparatifs

Je ne connais que la signification de "bien que" dans un sens de comparaison et je voudrais savoir quelle est la signification de l'expression "aussi bien pour" dans ce contexte:

> Nous devons en tenir compte dans nos analyses économiques et dans nos
>   analyses politiques, aussi bien pour déblayer le terrain de tant de
>   fausses problématiques, que pour être maîtres d'une méthodologie marxiste
>   toujours plus perfectionnée.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de la locution « bien que » ici, qui n'est d'ailleurs pas utilisée pour faire une comparaison, mais pour introduire une concession.

Answer (score 2):

« Aussi bien pour … que pour … » signifie simplement « pour l'un et pour l'autre » en insistant sur le fait que les deux raisons¹ sont importantes (en particulier celle que l'on aurait tendance à oublier).

—
<sup>1. ou buts, destinataires… n'importe quoi qui peut être introduit par *pour*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

La construction générale est « aussi bien A que B ». Elle n'a rien à voir avec « bien que ». « Aussi bien A que B » signifie en gros « A et B », en insistant sur le fait que A et B sont aussi importants l'un que l'autre.

Ainsi la phrase de la question pourrait être reformulée de manière plus lourde et moins idiomatique mais en gardant le sens ainsi :

> Nous devons en tenir compte dans nos analyses économiques et dans nos analyses politiques. Une raison à cela est de déblayer le terrain de tant de fausses problématiques. Une autre raison est d'être maîtres d'une méthodologie marxiste toujours plus perfectionnée.

A et B peuvent être des groupes nominaux introduits ou non par des prépositions, des adjectifs, des propositions à l'infinitif, ou des subordonnées, … Le fait que « aussi bien » soit suivi de *pour* n'est qu'un cas parmi d'autres.

- Des noms ou groupes nominaux, précédés ou nom d'une préposition.

  > La coordination des opérations concerne aussi bien la suite des opérations nécessaires à la réalisation d'une tâche que la gestion de deux tâches simultanées.   ([Jean-Pierre Rossi](http://books.google.fr/books?id=k147EFecoWoC&pg=PA24&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
  >
  > aussi bien à gauche qu'à droite   ([André Ropert](http://books.google.fr/books?id=trMMGyM4YxQC&pg=PA209&dq=%22aussi+bien+%C3%A0+gauche+qu%27%C3%A0+droite%22))
  >
  > une augmentation de la part du chômage aussi bien pour les hommes que pour les femmes   ([Centre d'étude de l'emploi](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NZATBhOjfGoC&pg=PT58&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))

  La préposition peut varier, du moment qu'il s'agit de compléments de même nature.

  > aussi bien dans la maison paternelle qu'à Saint-Acheul   ([Jean-Nicolas Loriquet](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mQHqnEJr8CQC&pg=PA275&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
  >
  > aussi bien après avoir mangé qu'à jeun   ([*Journal complémentaire du dictionnaire des sciences médicales*, 1826](http://books.google.fr/books?id=pwMHAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA234&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
- Des adjectifs.

  > l'Estonie […] manifestait d'emblée un désintérêt absolu envers les aspects aussi bien rouges que bruns  ([Jaan Kross, trad. Jacques Tricot](http://books.google.fr/books?id=kVsk1aZ5sIkC&pg=PA262&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
- Des subordonées.

  > allons sur le rivage, aussi bien pour voir le vaisseau qui est arrivé, que pour épier de nos yeux l'arrivée du brave Othello   ([William Shakespeare, trad. Émile Montégut](http://books.google.fr/books?id=yb83AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA374&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
  >
  > un cheval, par exemple, est détruit aussi bien s'il se change en homme qu'en insecte   [Faten Karoui-Bouchoucha](http://books.google.fr/books?id=CF34Udhxv_MC&pg=PA34&dq=%22aussi+bien%22)

Lorsque A et B sont compléments d'un nom, on peut reporter « aussi bien » devant le groupe nominal principal, et dans ce cas on peut reprendre ou nom le nom principal par un pronom.

> c'est vraiment le but commun, aussi bien du mécanicien que du physicien.   ([Thierry Magnin](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Gw1Z_6KVyScC&pg=RA1-PR22&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
>
> Le Musée de la Nation est aussi bien le foyer des Hellènes que celui des Philhellènes   ([Jean Gaitanos](http://books.google.fr/books?id=nB_aHAAACAAJ&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))
>
> c'est aussi bien le cas […] du thatchérisme que du reaganisme   ([Gaël Brustier](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5XxSk6GQaOAC&pg=PT36&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))

Lorsqu'il y a trois groupes, on peut utiliser « aussi bien A que B et que C » ou « aussi bien A que B ou que C ». Le choix entre *et* et *ou* dépend du contexte ; lorsqu'on a le choix, *et* donne une forte impression d'exhaustivité (on a énuméré toutes les possibilités) alors que *ou* est neutre. On peut aussi utiliser « ou encore », qui implique que la liste n'est pas exhaustive. Et on omet des fois le *que* après la conjonction de coordination (« aussi bien A que B et/ou C »). Avec quatre groupes ou plus, on met des virgules : « aussi bien A, que B, que C, ou que D ».

> aussi bien à gauche, qu'au centre et à droite   [Danic Parenteau](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3lQAWPIp7CkC&pg=PA162&dq=%22aussi+bien+%C3%A0+gauche+qu%27au+centre%22)
>
> Aussi bien à gauche qu'au centre ou qu'à droite !   [Jack Laffrat](http://books.google.fr/books?id=V0tZ8zX_eLsC&pg=PA52&dq=%22aussi+bien+%C3%A0+gauche+qu%27au+centre%22)
>
> Il pourrait prendre pour semence aussi bien le seigle ou l'orge que le froment.   ([J.-J. Bret](http://books.google.fr/books?id=7uxBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22aussi+bien%22))

On n'utilise jamais « aussi bien » dans une phrase négative. En général, la négation de « aussi bien A que B » est « ni A ni B ».

Attention, on peut rencontrer « aussi bien » dans d'autres sens, notamment :

- L'adverbe *bien* peut avoir son sens propre qui correspond à l'adjectif *bon* : « c'est aussi bien comme ça », « il dessine aussi bien qu'elle ».
- « Aussi bien » en tête de phrase est une locution vieillie qui signifie « après tout ».

Answer (score 1):

"Aussi bien pour A que pour B" signifie "for A, as well as for B". L'expression exprime l'existence de deux buts ou de deux raisons qui coexistent. Elle peut servir à insister sur la raison A, par opposition à la raison B qui est naturelle, mais pas nécéssairement.

La citation pourrait être traduite par:
"We must take this into account [...], for cleaning the field of all these wrong problematics, as well as for being (?) of an ever more developed marxist methodology."

La seconde partie de la phrase n'est pas absolument claire.